# Best way to iterate IntArray with Index in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

I am looking for a way to best way to iterate IntArray with index similar to below JAVA code

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
```

I am using below code where I do not want to iterate last element to avoid `IndexOutOfBoundException`. `A.indices` allows me to iterate all the indices while I do not want to touch last element just like above:

```
class Solution {
    fun isMonotonic(A: IntArray): Boolean {
        var increasing : Boolean = false
        var decreasing : Boolean = false

        for (i in A.indices) {
            if (A[i] <= A[i+1]) increasing = true
            if (A[i] >= A[i+1]) decreasing = true
        }

        return increasing && decreasing
    }
}
```

Comment: *I do not want to iterate last element to avoid IndexOutOfBoundException* you can access the last element. `IndexOutOfBoundException` will be thrown if you try to access a non existing element, with index < 0 or index >= arr.length.

Comment: You should instead use `for(i in 0 until A.lastIndex)`

Comment: Shouldn't the last line be `return !(increasing && decreasing)` to fit the definition of monotonic? You also don't handle the case of an array with 0 or 1 elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the functional approaches with immutable variables. Note that Array does not have `zipWithNext` hence have to convert to `Sequence` first

```
fun isMonotonic(A: IntArray): Boolean {
    val list = A.asSequence().zipWithNext()
    return !list.any { it.first < it.second } || !list.any { it.first > it.second }
}
```

**Edit** as per @sschuberth's comment, replaced List with Sequence for better performance.

Comment: You could use `asSequence()` instead of `toList()` to 1. wrap the array instead of creating a new collection, and 2. only evaluate as few items as needed.

Comment: You answered the question, but the result of the function is incorrect, monotonic means that all items are either entirely non-increasing or non-decreasing, as the answer from [deHaar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61868174/3231537) shows

Comment: thanks for the input. @Icepickle. I used the same logic that OP has in the question. But now updated the answer

Answer (score 3):

If you want to iterate the indices as a range, you can use the attribute `lastIndex` of `IntArray` in order to avoid an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Just don't compare an element with its successor, start with the second element and compare its predecessor to it while iterating from index 1 to the last index like this:

```
fun isMonotonic(A: IntArray): Boolean {
    var increasing : Boolean = false
    var decreasing : Boolean = false

    // iterate the range from 1 to the last index, starting with the second index
    for (i in 1..A.lastIndex) {
        val predecessor = A[i - 1]
        val successor = A[i]

        if (predecessor < successor) { 
            increasing = true
            println("${predecessor} < ${successor}")
        } else if (predecessor > successor) {
            decreasing = true
            println("${predecessor} > ${successor}")
        } else {
            println("${predecessor} = ${successor}")
        }

        // check if you can exit already (current state is not monotonic)
        if (increasing && decreasing) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // if no intermediate state was "not monotonic", this must be "monotonic"
    return true;
}
```

or like this (thanks for your comment, @AnimeshSahu):

```
fun isMonotonic(A: IntArray): Boolean {
    var increasing : Boolean = false
    var decreasing : Boolean = false

    // iterate the range from 0 to the second last index
    for (i in 0 until A.lastIndex) {
        val predecessor = A[i]
        val successor = A[i + 1]

        if (predecessor < successor) { 
            increasing = true
            println("${predecessor} < ${successor}")
        } else if (predecessor > successor) {
            decreasing = true
            println("${predecessor} > ${successor}")
        } else {
            println("${predecessor} = ${successor}")
        }

        // check if you can exit already (current state is not monotonic)
        if (increasing && decreasing) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // if no intermediate state was "not monotonic", this must be "monotonic"
    return true;
}
```

I have tried it the following way:

```
fun main() {
    var arr = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

    if (isMonotonic(arr)) {
        println("monotonic")
    } else {
        println("not monotonic")
    }
}
```

Which gave me the output

```
1 < 2
2 < 3
3 < 4
4 < 5
5 < 6
6 < 7
monotonic
```

while an input of `intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1)` resulted in

```
1 < 2
2 < 3
3 < 4
4 > 3
not monotonic
```

and the input `intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4)` brought up the output

```
1 < 2
2 < 3
3 < 4
4 = 4
4 = 4
4 = 4
monotonic
```

Comment: Couldn't you exit early if increasing is set and the next is decreasing, or vice versa?

Comment: @Icepickle I don't think so, because a monotony needs to be checked over the entire sequence (if you want a mathematically correct result). The full purpose for this code wasn't mentioned, so I just adapted as much as possible from the original example. Might be possible to exit earlier anyway...

Comment: From the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function), I found this *In calculus, a function {\displaystyle f}f defined on a subset of the real numbers with real values is called monotonic if and only if it is either entirely non-increasing, or entirely non-decreasing. That is, as per Fig. 1, a function that increases monotonically does not exclusively have to increase, it simply must not decrease.* Doesn't that imply that as soon as the direction changes it's no longer monotonic?

Comment: @Icepickle yes, it does... I was obviously wrong ;-) You can check in the loop (another `if`-statement between the `for`-loop and the return statement) if both are true and then immediately exit, I think... The return value at the end might then just be `true` because the case of `false` would have been checked before.

Comment: @Icepickle you were so right, I just had to update my answer to include the early exit strategy

Answer (score 2):

In kotlin

`for (x in 0 until 10) println(x) // Prints 0 through 9`

In this case you can do it like this:

```kotlin
for(i in 0 until A.lastIndex) {
  if(A[i] <= A[i+1]) increasing = true
  if(A[i] >= A[i+1]) decreasing = true
}
```

[official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/loops.html)

Comment: `0 until A.size` is same as `A.indices` when going `i+1` you will get IndexOutOfBound exception.